# Triple integration problem by changing to polar co-ordinate

Tags: integration

I have this question

> Evaluate the triple integral:
>   $$\int_0^1 \int_0^{\sqrt (1-x^2)} \int_0^{\sqrt (1-x^2-y^2)} xyz~dx~dy~dx$$

My attemp:
Changing to polar co-ordinates. 

Let $$\begin{align}
x=rsin\theta cos\phi \\
y=rsin\theta sin \phi \\
z=rcos\theta
\end{align}$$
The new integrals becomes
$$\int_0^1 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} \int_{\phi=0}^{\pi/2} rsin\theta cos\phi
rsin\theta sin \phi 
rcos\theta|J|~dx~dy~dx$$
where $|J|$ is the Jacobian of transformation. Evaluating this, gives me the value of the integral as $\frac 1{144}$. However the answer is $\frac 1{48}$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian is $r^2 \sin{\theta}$, so the integral is

$$\underbrace{\int_0^1 dr \, r^5}_{1/6} \underbrace{\, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \sin^3{\theta} \cos{\theta}}_{1/4} \, \underbrace{\int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi \, \cos{\phi} \sin{\phi}}_{1/2} $$